# How to generate correlated non ordered nominal variables in R?

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

I need to generate two samples with N non ordered nominal variables where each variable has different number of levels:

1 sample: 3d variable depends on 2nd.

2 sample: all variables depends on 1st.

How to do this in R (or C++ via Rcpp)? Could you advise some package or general idea?

I have found `rmult.bcl` function in SimCorMultRes package but as I understand it's impossible to generate nominal variables with different number of levels with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand what you are asking for with Sample 1 and Sample 2, but it is not hard to make the distribution of one variable depend on the contents of another. I will illustrate with two variables. The distribution of values in V2 depends on the values in V1.

```
set.seed(2019)
V1 = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace=TRUE)
NumA = sum(V1 == "A")
V2 = character(100)
V2[V1 == "A"] = sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), NumA, replace=TRUE)
V2[V1 != "A"] = sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 100-NumA, 
    prob=c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1),  replace=TRUE)
table(V1,V2)
   V2
V1   X  Y  Z
  A 11 24 18
  B 30 14  3
```

Comment: Perfect @G5W! But I don't realize how to generalize your code in case of more than two levels in V1 variable

Comment: For more that two levels in V1, instead of using `V2[V1 == "A"] = ...` and `V2[V1 != "A"] = … `   use `V2[V1 == "A"] = ...`  `V2[V1 == "B"] = ...` and `V2[V1 == "C"] = ...`